# How to add a file to the first commit on a git repo?

Tags: git, rebase

I have been converting old SVN repos to GIT. I have gotten the branches and tags to convert. Including making SVN tags real tags in GIT.

However, I would like to add a gitignore to the very first commit in the newly created GIT repo. I want it to be as if the file had always been there. So all the commits that followed (on master or in branches) would now have this file as the parent tree(s) would lead back the the first commit.

It seems that some form of git rebase or git filter-branch --tree-filter is what I need. I have tried each of these but I end up with disconnected branches.

Comment: You can easily do this for single branch using `git rebase -i`. But I'm not sure how to do it for all branches and tags in the whole repo.

Comment: Yep. It was pretty easy for a single branch. I really am trying to "rewrite" history. I want to make it as if I added the gitignore from the beginning and everything flowed from there.

Answer (score 23):

I recently had to modify an early commit because of a problematic typo in the commit message. This works for changing anything about a previous commit. I modified [Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey)'s answer to [Combine the first two commits of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435646/how-do-i-combine-the-first-two-commits-of-a-git-repository)

```bash
# Go back to the commit you want to change (detach HEAD)
git checkout <sha1_for_commit_to_change>

# Make any changes now (add your new file) then add them to the index
git add <new_files>

# amend the current commit
git commit --amend

# temporarily tag this new commit
# (or you could remember the new commit sha1 manually)
git tag tmp

# go back to the original branch (assume master for this example)
git checkout master

# Replay all the commits after the change onto the new initial commit
git rebase --rebase-merges --onto tmp <sha1_for_commit_to_change>

# remove the temporary tag
git tag -d tmp
```

Note that this will change all of your commit IDs following the amended commit, so it's not recommended on a public repository. Also, you'll have to recreate all of your tags

Answer (score 1):

Do this on a clean working tree, on a new clone if you wish:

```
$ git checkout -b withgitignore $firstcommithash
$ git add .gitignore
$ git commit --amend
$ for branch in branch1 branch2 branch3 ... ; do
      git checkout $branch
      git rebase withgitignore
   done
```

Untested ;)

Comment: I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: The only reason that I could think of why it wouldn't work is because one or more of the branches (or commits pointed to by the tags) did not share the same first commit. Could you verify that this is the case by doing something like 'git log --oneline branch|tail -1'? Compare the result for all branches and tags.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. My wife gave birth early been busy! I checked each branch/tag and every one had the same first commit. I'm going to try it again and see if I can give further info.

Comment: Congratulations on being a father! Please tell your wife a random stranger wishes all the best for the whole family. As a father of two all I can say is that children can give you immeasurable happiness.

Comment: Well, I tried it again and it didn't work. It goes through the motions but the gitignore file is not in any of the branches or tags when I switch/checkout them. Oh and thanks for the well wishes. 2 kid for me too. Definitely not a linear difficulty curve! Much harder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a brand new rebuild, then one trick is to start a branch at that first commit and add the gitignore there. You now have the 'right' commit at the head of that branch. Now for the trick - you use the `grafts` facility to reorder the perceived commit sequence. A plain `git filter-branch` will make it permanent, though the old hierarchy will be still be listed under `originals` in refs\info (IIRC).

While this will create an early commit that contains the gitignore file, all the other commits will still be without the gitignore file.

Edit:----------
The [git-filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), gives examples:

`git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm filename' HEAD`, and a `--index-filter` variant.

You could simply `add .gitignore` your .gitignore instead of the remove, and use the `--index-filter` so that your work tree is still intact for copying from.

Make sure you have a backup first though ! 
Report if it works for you.

Comment: Hmmm. It still seems that this won't help the other commits. It isn't so much that I want the commit reordered, rather I'm hoping to achieve something that allow the other commits to "inherit" the newly added file. I'll read more on the --index-filter though in case I misunderstand.

Comment: What the command should do is go through each commit, one by one, and perform the filter action, which in this case is to add your `.gitignore`, and then re-write the commit. At the end of the command, if you use `gitk --all` you should see the newly formed branch, with every commit having `.gitignore` included, plus an `originals` pseudo branch 'just in case'.

Comment: I tried copying the gitignore into the working tree and then `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git add gitignore' HEAD --index-filter`, but I get this error: *fatal: ambiguous argument 'add': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.*

Comment: @Carl: the `tree-filter` was the man page example. Have you tried it with the suggested `--index-filter`? i.e `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git add gitignore'` HEAD is assumed (is it `.gitignore`, or simply `gitignore`?)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. My wife gave birth early been busy! Anyway, I tried `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git add gitignore' HEAD`, `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git add gitignore'`, `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git add .gitignore'` and in each case still got the same error

Comment: @Carl, Congratulations, I hope everyone is well.