# Delete first commits in github

Tags: git, github

At the beginning I committed a few test commits with 600k+ rows of Code. After that I deleted all files and just used git like normal.

Now I see in the contributors statistic that I added and deleted over 650k+ rows of Code.

Is there a way to delete the first test commits?
(I just want to get the statistic right)

Edit: that's my commit history:

- 1 Commit: +600k rows (Initial commit)
- 2 Commit: -600k rows (master is now empty)
- 3 Commit: +100 rows (just gitignore) <-- I would like to have this as initial commit
- 4 Commit: +30k rows (my normal work)
  ...

Comment: You can, but I don think that it will hurt the spirit of git, namely keeping track of history.

Comment: you can do git squash

Comment: @Alexan Isn't git squash only applicable only for the last n commits?

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName I know but I did the first commits just to test if I can commit somehting. It doesnt even have to do with the current work (Ist my first time with git, thats why I tested it)

Comment: @sirzento I think the only way is to use a clean branch and manually fix the first commits ... then merge the ones afterwards from the current branch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435646/combine-the-first-two-commits-of-a-git-repository

Comment: would this remove the 600k+ rows from the contributors statistic but Keep my statistic after that?

Comment: Maybe you want just this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName you mean I change the test commits to another user so my statistics are fine and just have a 'testuser' with the commits?

Comment: Actually, @Alexan 's suggestion will let you remove any commit, including the initial one. This will truly delete their data (well, almost: at least if you `push` them, the server won't have these data).

Comment: @Ruslan Isnt this link to a question how to combine commits and not how to delete?

Comment: `git rebase -i` can do all these things: edit, squash, remove... Just try it: the comments in the config file which will open are pretty well written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the branch is called master and it has 10 linear revisions.

```
git checkout master~7 # checkout the 3rd revision from history
git reset --soft master~9 # set branch pointer at first revision, all diffs between master~7 and master~9 are on index
git commit --amend --no-edit # now first revision has the content (working tree) of master~7, so first two revisions from master are gone
git cherry-pick master~7..master # replay history
# if you like the result
git branch -f master # set master on new branch
git checkout master
```

Comment: So with say 30 Revision and want to have the 4th commit as start it would be: checkout master~26, --soft master~29 and cherry-pick master~26 ?

Comment: One last question. i have a merge of 1 file. the merge was with '17a9c4b' + '1e43056'  into commit '47f92b3'. Would be `git cherry-pick master~26..master -m 1 47f92b3` correct if the change from 1e43056 can be dropped and use the first parent?

Comment: I guess you could use the options for cherry-pick that keep merges in history.