# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged but overwrite server

Tags: git, github

I just did [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56150997/10122822) and deleted some of my first commits.
After the last step I got this
 `Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have 27 and 32 different commits each, respectively (use 'git pull' to merge the remote branch into yours)`
I now want to push this to github so that only the 27 commits I currently have local are shown on github.

Do I only need to make a normal push?

(Other questions ask how to solve this Problem with merging but I want to throw away whats on the Server and overwrite it with my local datas so the first commits doesnt Exits anymore)

Comment: what does `git status` give ?

Comment: The same as the code-formated part I added in now.

Comment: `git push -f` will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to completely override the remote commits you may use `git push -f` (force push).